# Moving one large archive, or many individual files and folders?

Tags: performance, file-management, file-transfer

Is it faster to move files between media in large pieces (i.e. many files and folders within an archive) or move them file-by-file? Is there a significant difference, considering that the file transfer completes with no errors?

Comment: "Better" how?  Faster?  Less chance of corruption?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which is faster, copying everything at once or one thing at a time?](http://superuser.com/questions/252959/which-is-faster-copying-everything-at-once-or-one-thing-at-a-time)

Comment: @techie007 I meant faster. Edited!

Comment: @techie007 This is not a duplicate, as they are asking about a queue of file transfers. I am asking about transferring the files as a single archive (e.g. *.zip), as opposed to file-by-file (individually).

Comment: Do you count the time of archiving and unarchiving? which basically means one copy at each side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If contents and size are equal, then transferring one file should be faster due to only having one header/index entry to deal with.  The setup and tear-down overhead of many files can add significant time to the transfers.

See this SU question for more info: [Why does copying the same amount of data take longer if spread across many separate files?](https://superuser.com/questions/344534/why-does-copying-the-same-amount-of-data-take-longer-if-spread-across-many-separ)